# Building Python add-ins without needing to restart ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, python-addin

Using the Python add-in wizard I need to restart ArcMap every time I want to test something.  For example, when I've got syntax errors or something little that I need to troubleshoot.

What approach would you recommend to negate the need to start ArcMap repeatedly?

It has been noted in comments that this question has already been asked and vaguely answered; however it's totally unclear to me how you integrate this into your script.

Can someone give me an example?

I've tried to include the following script as noted in the other question linked here.

```
import os

esri = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\ESRIRegAddIn.exe"
cwd = os.getcwd()

mapdoc = "C:\Data\Shaun Pilot Area\PilotAreaMXD.mxd"

try: os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM ArcMap.exe")
except: pass

os.system(os.path.join(cwd, "makeaddin.py"))

os.system('"{0}" {1} /s'.format(esri, os.path.split(cwd)[-1] + ".esriaddin")

os.system(mapdoc)
```

Here's the output I get

```
ERROR: The process "ArcMap.exe" not found.
'C:\Data\Shaun' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
'C:\Data\Shaun' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea; but I'm completely baffled as to how to implement it.  I would like to see an answer that illustrates how to implement it!

Comment: Have you looked at the given answers and tried them? Where are you stuck? What have you tried so far? You are unlikely to get a step by step tutorial on how to do it.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I've updated the question to include my code and error message.

Comment: Be sure you are handling your backslashes correctly, as they are an escape character in Python string literals. I like to use the `r` prefix, e.g. `r"somestring"`, although you could also double up the backslashes or replace them with forward slashes. Not sure that is the problem in this case, but it's a start.

Comment: Also I would only use the script you are using if you are testing changes to the add-in definition and entry points. If you are testing changes to logic you have encapsulated in separate modules (which you should do BTW), then the reload method suggested in the accepted answer of the linked question is what I recommend.